# learnable segmentation or learnable edge detection

Tags: edge-detection, image-segmentation

Is there some learnable segmentation or learnable edge detection algorithm exist?

For example I mark N fotos by hands and than program "learns" how to do it best way and can do it on similar images.

there are some papers on this subject or source code?

Update:
I found some inforamtion supervised edge detection \ supervised segmentation
http://www.loni.ucla.edu/~ztu/Download.htm

but still looking for code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a benchmark code and test and learning dataset to perform image segmentation with ground truth dataset at [Berkeley website](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/Research/Projects/CS/vision/bsds/) and the [code](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/Research/Projects/CS/vision/bsds/code/segbench.tar.gz) in the same place.

Comment: Please provide context for your links. Here's more on [how to write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer). While it's nice you're trying to contribute, providing some context, one-or-two sentence description on why you think this is helpful. Here's just [one of the discussions on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231) that reflects the community stance on link-only answers.

Comment: I guess hes precisely describes in his question most details, anyway edited to reflect the keywords.